# Why doesn't this number guessing program continue past this line?

Tags: python-3.x

The following code is for guessing Number game. It has no errors but doesn't give a output. How can I further improve the code?

It works till this line `print("Your Number has been Generated,Enter your guess Below")` but then does not give any output.

```
     #Guess the number

     from random import randint

     print("Welcome to Guess the Number Game:")
     print("Press 'g' to Generate Number between 0 and 100:")

     cmd=input("->")

    if cmd=='g':
       num=randint(0,100)
    else:
       print("Unknown Input")


    def chk(x):
        if int(x)==True:
           chk=True
        else:
           chk=False

    def diff(x,y):
        diff=(x-y)
        return diff

    print("Your Number has been Generated,Enter your guess Below")
    guess=input("->")

    chk(guess)

    while chk==True:
    diff(num,guess)
    if diff==0:
    print("Congrats! correct Guess")

    elif diff>10:
    print("Oh! too high")

    elif diff<5 and diff>0:
    print("very close!Better Luck Next time")

    else:
    diff<0
    print("Sorry!too Low")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with the, some of which may transcribing issues:

```
def chk(x):
    if int(x)==True:
       chk=True
    else:
       chk=False
```

I presume this is meant to `check` input. Depending on the version of python this will always set `chk` to false. This is because `int` returns an integer, which is not the same type as a boolean `True`. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. Looks like you want to check that the input is a number. Instead why not use [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)? Because, at the moment, your code returns false you never enter the `while` loop

You also haven't indented your while loop correctly, as a rule of thumb, things like `if` and `while` statements need a new line and an indentation afterwards.

So this might be better code to use:

```
# keep guessing while it's a digit
while guess.isdigit():
    # assign the difference to a variable
    # don't forget to indent after the while statement
    diff = diff(num, int(guess))
    if diff==0:
        # indent again!
        print("Congrats! correct Guess")

    elif diff>10:
        print("Oh! too high")

    elif diff<5 and diff>0:
        print("very close!Better Luck Next time")

    elif diff<0:
        print("Sorry!too Low")
```

That ways you don't need `chk` at all.

Comment: You are right, I was using def chk(x) to check if the input is a number, I will keep the indentation rule of thumb in mind. Thanks for the Help

Comment: what i was thinking in chk(x) was that if the input is anything other than number ie if a string then int(string) will not be possible, therefore the condition int(x)==true will be false, Now I have understood. thanks for the insight

Comment: @RohanDwivedi what actually happens is that an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers already given, but you can do this with a very 'flat' script, without defining functions. This only as an example:

```
from random import randint

# welcome
print("Welcome to Guess the Number Game:")

# loop until 'g' is given
cmd = ''
while not cmd == 'g':
    print("Press 'g' and '<enter>' to Generate Number between 0 and 100:")
    cmd = input("->")       

# generates a random number
num = randint(0,100)
print("Your Number has been Generated,Enter your guess Below")

# loops until correct answer is guessed
while True:
    try:
        guess=int(input("guess->"))
    except ValueError:
        print('Numbers only please')
        continue
    if guess > num: 
        print('too high')
    if guess < num: 
        print('too low')        
    if guess == num:
        print("Congrats! correct Guess")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple issues, I have shown this by using comments

```
from random import randint

print("Welcome to Guess the Number Game:")
print("Press 'g' to Generate Number between 0 and 100:")

cmd=input("->")

if cmd=='g':
       num=randint(0,100)
else:
       print("Unknown Input")


def chk(x):
    if x.isnumeric(): # needs to be '.isNumeric()' as only the only integer that will return true is '1'
           chk=True
    else:
            chk=False
    return chk #Returns Boolean

def diff(x,y):
        return (y-x)# this needs to y-x to be correct

print("Your Number has been Generated,Enter your guess Below")
guess=input("->")

while chk(guess): #or chk(guess) == True
    difference = diff(num,int(guess))#guess needs to be an INTEGER
    if difference==0:
        print("Congrats! correct Guess")
        exit()

if difference>10:
    print("Oh! too high")

elif difference<5 and difference>0:
    print("very close!Better Luck Next time")

elif difference<0:
    print("Sorry!too Low")
print("Enter your guess Below")#allows you to put in another guess
guess=input("->")#sets the guess variable
chk(guess)
```